# JavaScript test failing - checking for similar items, true if one item or less needs to be switched

Tags: javascript, testing

Working on this code for a test, passing some but failing others.

**Problem:**

> Two arrays are called similar if one can be obtained from another by swapping at most one pair of elements in one of the arrays.
>
> Given two arrays a and b, check whether they are similar.

**Example:**

> For a = [1, 2, 3] and b = [1, 2, 3], the output should be
>   areSimilar(a, b) = true.
>
> The arrays are equal, no need to swap any elements.
>
> For a = [1, 2, 3] and b = [2, 1, 3], the output should be
>   areSimilar(a, b) = true.

**My Solution**:

```js
function areSimilar(a, b) {    
    var error = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
       
        if(a[i] === b[i]){
            return true;
        } else if(a[i] !== b[i]){
            error++;
        }
    }
        if(error > 1){
            return false;
        } else{
            return true;
        }
}
```

**Example of Test Passed:**

> Input:
>
> a: [1, 2, 2]
>   b: [2, 1, 1]
>
> Output:
>
> false
>
> Expected Output:
>
> false

**Example of Test Failed:**

> Input:
>
> a: [2, 3, 9]
>   b: [10, 3, 2]
>
> Output:
>
> true
>
> Expected Output:
>
> false

Comment: Can you describe how you think this algorithm should work (in pseudo code)?

Comment: @Halcyon - Check if a matches b perfectly, if yes return true. If not, check whether element in array a matches the same element in array b. if that is not true, add 1 count to error. loop through all array elements. if error is greater than one, return false because we should only have to switch one item.  ******** now that I am reading it I think I have it wrong. if two numbers don't match, error returns false although I never tried swapping those elements to see if they would match if so

Comment: Yea you need to swap elements in `a` to see if you can get to `b`. My initial thought we be to just try all possible pair-swaps in `a` and see if we match `b`.

Comment: @Halcyon I am thinking.. should I try sorting it and then seeing if one item doesn't match, splice it, then test again? True or false accordingly?

Comment: the examples are kind of misleading.  one thing that helped me was to also test for cases where the pairs are not next to each other.  i find the first mismatch then get the index in the other array and see if swapping that pair will work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution.

```js
function swapPair(a, i, j) {
 var temp;
 temp = a[i];
 a[i] = a[j];
 a[j] = temp;
 return a;
}

function areSame(a, b) {
 var i;
 for (i = 0; i < a.length; i += 1) {
  if (a[i] !== b[i]) {
   return false;
  }
 }
 return true;
}

function areSimilar(a, b) {
 var i, temp;
 for (i = 0; i < a.length; i += 1) {
  // do we need to try a swap?
  if (a[i] !== b[i]) {
   for (j = i + 1; j < a.length; j += 1) {
    a = swapPair(a, i, j);
    if (areSame(a, b) === true) { // do we have a match now?
     return true;
    } else {
     a = swapPair(a, i, j); // swap back so we can try another pair
    }
   }
   // we could not find a swap that satisfies areSame(a, b)
   return false;
  }
 }
 // no swap was required
 return true;
}

console.log(areSimilar([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]) === true);
console.log(areSimilar([1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3]) === true);
console.log(areSimilar([1, 2, 2], [2, 1, 1]) === false);
console.log(areSimilar([2, 3, 9], [10, 3, 2]) === false);
console.log(areSimilar([2, 3, 1], [1, 3, 2]) === true);
console.log(areSimilar([832, 998, 148, 570, 533, 561, 894, 147, 455, 279], [832, 998, 148, 570, 533, 561, 455, 147, 894, 279]) === true);
console.log(areSimilar([2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2]) === true);
```

Comment: thanks! I tried the solution, but see 3 errors still (7/10 tests passed) Input:
a: [1, 2, 2]
b: [2, 1, 1]
Output:
true
Expected Output:
false


Input:
a: [2, 3, 1]
b: [1, 3, 2]
Output:
false
Expected Output:
true

Input:
a: [832, 998, 148, 570, 533, 561, 894, 147, 455, 279]
b: [832, 998, 148, 570, 533, 561, 455, 147, 894, 279]
Output:
false
Expected Output:
true

Comment: By the way, thank you for all your help! I love love LOVE how you add pseudo code so I can better understand. It helps a ton being new & learning 100% solo

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood part of the question. I assumed the pairs had to be next to each other. I'll find another solution.

Comment: I've made a new solution. It passes for all the cases you've given.

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much! Probably a silly question, but could you explain what that first part does? The swapPair function? If I am understanding correctly, it takes one element in the array and swaps it with the next, and so on?

Comment: Correct. We try a swap on `i` and `i+1`, if we match we accept the swap; otherwise we swap them back and try `i` and `i+2` and so on. If we don't find a suitable swap we know we can't match `a` and `b` so we can return early. You could upgrade this algorithm to accept `n` swaps.

Comment: Hmm. just tried to submit it and theres a hidden test it is failing. Mind you, the test is hidden so  can't figure out why it's failing.. I guess I will revisit and think of all cases it may fail

Comment: Perhaps it fails on cases where `a.length != b.length`. I made the assumption that the arrays are balanced.

Comment: No, it's constrained - Guaranteed constraints:
b.length = a.length

Comment: It's failing on this : a = [2,1,1] b = [1,1,2] Expected Output: true

Comment: I found the bug. What happens is that it swaps index `0` and `1` to get `1,2,1` this satisfied `a[i] === b[i]` so the swap is accepted, but then it tests the next value and the swap is no good. I've amended the code, it now only accepts the swap if it results in `areSame(a, b) === true`.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand right your problem, i think something like this should works

**EDIT**

```
function areSimilar(a, b) {

   var isSimilar = true
   var isAlreadySwap = false

   a.forEach(function(item, index){
      if(item !== b[index] && item === b[index+1] && !isAlreadySwap){
         var temp = b[index]
         b[index] = b[index+1]
         b[index+1] = temp
         isAlreadySwap = true
      }else if(item !== b[index]){
         isSimilar = false;
         return;
      }
   })

   return isSimilar
}
```

Comment: It doesn't quite work. `areSimilar([1,2,3,4],[2,1,4,3])` should return `false`. I swapped **2** pairs.

Comment: Sorry i miss this part of the problem, see my edit above

Comment: @CédricGuérin Thanks! it passed 8/10 tests, but still failed the following two: Input:
a: [2, 3, 1]
b: [1, 3, 2]
Output:
false
Expected Output:
true

Input:
a: [832, 998, 148, 570, 533, 561, 894, 147, 455, 279]
b: [832, 998, 148, 570, 533, 561, 455, 147, 894, 279]
Output:
false
Expected Output:
true